# How to theme the blog module - node--blog.tpl.php?

Tags: theming, nodes

I'm really struggling to theme the blog module, all the tutorials I find seem to revolve around creating a node-blog.tpl.php but this template is not picked up by my theme (omega sub theme, Drupal 7).

I have created a node--blog.tpl.php and it seems this template can be used to theme a single blog, and each single blog on a blog/uid page.

I'm looking for a base template I can use for this purpose - is there one?  Or do I simply have to do a $arr = get_defined_vars(); and pull everything out of the page variables.  Seems a bit laborious to save the least?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I suspect the blog module is simply a red herring, as useless and badly documented as it it.  Anyone else searching fr this, I recommend using a custom content type and using views to display multi user blogs.  So annoying that it is still left in Drupal 7..

Comment: I suggest you try the [devel_themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module for all the tasks related to theme template hunting.